# Get only the last text from a TextView list using accessibility

Tags: java, android

I get the texts from all the TextView, add them to a list and then get them with textViewNodes.size() - 3 ).getText() which is the last message sent or received.
I have two problems:
1st - Due to the use of the TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED event, any change that occurs on the screen runs the code again and I get the same list containing the texts several times.
2nd When scrolling the scrollview of the message screen, the code is executed again and I get the same list of texts several times.
My idea is to get only once the last messages that are received or sent.

[image]
[image]

```
package com.system.wifi.service;

import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

    List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> textViewNodes;

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();
        Log.d("TAG", "onServiceConnected................................................");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onAccessibilityEvent..............................................");

        textViewNodes = new ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo>();
  
        
        AccessibilityNodeInfo rootNode = getRootInActiveWindow();
   
        
        if(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED == event.getEventType()) {
            Log.e("TAG", "TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED.....................................");
                
            AccessibilityNodeInfo resultFindNameInterlocutor = findNameInterlocutor(rootNode, "com.gbwhatsapp:id/conversation_contact_name");
            
            if(resultFindNameInterlocutor != null){
                Log.d("TAG", "Interlocutor...................." + resultFindNameInterlocutor.getText());
            }

        }


        if(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED == event.getEventType()) {
            Log.e("TAG", "TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED.....................................");

            if (rootNode == null) {
                Log.d("TAG", "source é nulo................... .........................");
                return;
            }



            AccessibilityNodeInfo resultFindBoxMessage = findBoxMessage(rootNode, "com.gbwhatsapp:id/entry");
            
            if(resultFindBoxMessage != null){
                    
                findChildViews(rootNode);
                        
                if(!textViewNodes.isEmpty()){
                        
                    if(textViewNodes.get( textViewNodes.size() - 3 ).getText() != null){
                            
                        Log.d("TAG", textViewNodes.get( textViewNodes.size() - 3 ).getText().toString());
                        
                        Log.d("TAG", textViewNodes.get( textViewNodes.size() - 2 ).getText().toString());

                    }
                }
            }

        }

        rootNode.recycle();

    }

    

    
    private static AccessibilityNodeInfo findNameInterlocutor(AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo, String id){

        if (nodeInfo == null || nodeInfo.getClassName() == null) {
            return nodeInfo;
        }

        List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> nodeInfos = nodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId(id);

        if(nodeInfos.size() == 0){
            return null;
        }
        return nodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId(id).get(0);

    }

    
    private static AccessibilityNodeInfo findBoxMessage(AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo, String id){

        if (nodeInfo == null || nodeInfo.getClassName() == null) {
            return nodeInfo;
        }

        List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> nodeInfos = nodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId(id);

        if(nodeInfos.size() == 0){
            return null;
        }
        return nodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId(id).get(0);
    }


    
    private AccessibilityNodeInfo findChildViews(AccessibilityNodeInfo parentView) {


        if (parentView == null || parentView.getClassName() == null) {
            return parentView;
        }

        int childCount = parentView.getChildCount();

        if (childCount == 0 && (parentView.getClassName().toString().contentEquals("android.widget.TextView"))) {

            
            textViewNodes.add(parentView);

        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                findChildViews(parentView.getChild(i));
            }
        }
        return parentView;
    }



    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        Log.d("TAG", "onInterrupt.......................................................");
    }
}
```